# Read json file in httmclient method Angular

Tags: angular, observable, httpclient

I have a little problem, I want display data in my html page, I use a service in this service I use httpclient like this : http.get("./users.json") but it's not work, I have an error, how can I resolve this error, Thnaks fo answers :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Au1q.png)

**user.service.ts**

```
getUsers() : Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get("./users.json").pipe(map(data=>{
        let usersList = data["userList"];
        return usersList.map(function(user:any) {
            return {name: user.userName, age: user.userAge};
        });
    }));
}
```

**user.component.ts**

```
users: User[] = [];
constructor(private userService: UserService){}
ngOnInit(){
   this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(data => this.users=data);
}
```

**user.component.html**

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users">
   <p>Name: {{user?.name}}</p>
   <p>Age: {{user?.age}}</p>
</li>
```

Comment: if you really need to really on `http` request to get that file you need to add the json file into angular assets, but i would suggest jus using `import data from 'some.config'` or even better via dependency injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's about the link : put your file under the assets folder and try this code :

```
return this.http.get<any>('assets/users.json')
```